# Request for member X of Y which is of non-class type Z

Tags: c++

When trying to compile the following snippet of C++ code (complete source below)

```
A::A(istream& i) {
    vector<string> words( istream_iterator<int>(i), istream_iterator<int> );
    words.begin();
 }
```

I'm getting the error

```
istream_it.cpp:12: error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘words’, which is of non-class type 
‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >(
    std::istream_iterator<int, char, std::char_traits<char>, long int>,
    std::istream_iterator<int, char, std::char_traits<char>, long int>)’
```

I know this error is usually caused by accidentally declaring a function using the no-parameters operator, as in

```
string s(); s.size();
```

but in this case, I've already stripped all unnecessary code, and still cant see what exactly is going wrong, or what the correct syntax would be.

Full source:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A(istream& i) {
        vector<int> words(istream_iterator<int>(i), istream_iterator<int> );
        words.begin();
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    istringstream iss("1 2 3");
    A a(iss);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct,

```
vector<int> words(istream_iterator<int>(i), istream_iterator<int> );
```

this is a function named words taking two `istream_iterator<int>` parameters, one of which named i and the other has no name, and returning vector. Change to this:

```
vector<int> words((istream_iterator<int>(i)), istream_iterator<int>() );
```

The first parentheses added `(istream_iterator<int>(i))` make it an expression so there will be no ambiguity. The other parentheses `istream_iterator<int>()` are mandatory because you **construct** a temporary. A type by itself, like `istream_iterator<int>`, doesn't construct a temporary.

Comment: This works, but may I ask how the first istream_iterator could be recognized as a parameter named i? When I try to declare a function like 'int main(int(argc), char**argv)', the compiler is throwing an error

Comment: @Benno: mine don't and your shouldn't. What it says?

Comment: Oh, never mind, I got confused: There was another error in the same line.